# Create MATLAB Array in MEX C++ from a std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, vector, mex

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to create a MATLAB array from a `std::vector` than what I did and wrote below.

I found a simpler implementation in a question in the following Matlab forum, but the question still persists. [MathWorks: Copying std::vector contents to TypedArray](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/556525-copying-std-vector-contents-to-typedarray)

I used buffers, based on the way `matlab::data::SparseArray`s are made ([C++ class to create arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.arrayfactory.html#bvn7dve-1)).
Disclaimer: I'm really new to this!

Suppose we have a vector `V` of doubles:

```
matlab::data::ArrayFactory f;

// these objects are std::unique_ptr<T[],matlab::data::buffer_deleter_t>
auto V_b_ptr = f.createBuffer<double>(V.size());

// this pointer points to the first adress that the std::unique_ptr points to
double* V_ptr = V_b_ptr.get();

// fill the buffer with the V values
std::for_each(V.begin(), V.end(), [&](const double& e) {*(V_ptr++) = e;} );

// finally create Matlab array from buffer
matlab::data::TypedArray<double> A = f.createArrayFromBuffer<double>({1, V.size()}, std::move(V_b_ptr));
```

In the second link, there seems to be a way to use `factory.createArray(...)` in such a way that it is filled with a given data. But I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the question after hours of trying to figure things out by myself. But before submitting it, I gave it another hour. And I finally managed to do it. I'm posting the solution here in case it helps anyone.

As in the example in the question, supposing we have a `std::vector` of doubles `V`.

```
matlab::data::ArrayFactory f;
matlab::data::TypedArray<double> A = f.createArray<double>({1, V.size()}, V.data(), V.data()+V.size());
```